# Android malware samples come in binary format (octet-stream). How to convert it back to normal file for analysis?

Tags: android, malware

I obtained malware samples from this source for a school analysis project. (https://github.com/ashishb/android-malware)
But a lot of the samples are in binary format. Why this is a case and how can I convert it back to normal form?

Also I notice SHA1 being mentioned multiple times from different sources. What is the significant of this value? Why they giving this out instead of source code?

Comment: Uhm, wht is the 'normal form'?

Comment: source code, apk or zip

Comment: Try giving those a .apk or .zip file extension.

Comment: I did try this. Would give me 'An error occurred while loading the archive'

Comment: Why are they not giving out the source code? Because the people who write malware are not known to be forthcomming in providing the source code to those who want to analyze and defeat malware. They don't **want** to be beaten, so they try to obfuscate and hide the workings. And no one else can "give out the source code".

Comment: these binary files have similar size as other .apk or zip files

Comment: These files might also be Android Archive (AAR) or C++ libs. I think the best way is to give them a .bin extension and then try to find out by their content what they actually are...